# Testing the extent to which one variable depends on three others

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I developed a protocol for the assessment of trachea diameters in CT-images. To test this protocol I performed an experiment.

I have 30 CT-scans all containing multiple images (slices). I have asked 3 radiologists to identify the slice with smallest trachea dimensions for each of these 30 scans by visual inspection. After selection of this slice, the radiologist had to measure the diameter of the trachea according to my protocol, in that particular slice. After a month I repeated this experiment. So in total 180 (3x2x30) diameters were documented. Obviously, these various measurements yielded different results. To illustrate my problem I provide a selection of my data.

[image: data]

As you can see the documented diameters differ. I want to know how to what extent these differences are caused by time of measurement, the radiologist and the selected slice. How do I perform such an analysis?